# How to override _UpdatePrice function in vendor\magento\module-swatches\view\frontend\web\js\swatch-renderer.js

Tags: magento2, requirejs

in my app\code\X\Y\view\frontend\requirejs-config.js I have:

```
var config = {
    map: {
        '*': {
            'configurable':'X_Y/js/configurable',
            'swatchRenderer':'X_Y/js/swatchRenderer'

        }
    }
};
```

in my app\code\X\Y\view\frontend\web\js\swatch_renderer.js I have

```
define([
    'jquery',
    'underscore',
    'Magento_Swatches/js/swatchRenderer'
], function ($, _, swatchRenderer) {
    'use strict';
    _.extend(swatchRenderer.prototype, {

        _UpdatePrice: function () {
            var $widget = this,
                $product = $widget.element.parents($widget.options.selectorProduct),
                $productPrice = $product.find(this.options.selectorProductPrice),
                options = _.object(_.keys($widget.optionsMap), {}),
                result;

            $widget.element.find('.' + $widget.options.classes.attributeClass + '[option-selected]').each(function () {
                var attributeId = $(this).attr('attribute-id');

                options[attributeId] = $(this).attr('option-selected');
            });

            result = $widget.options.jsonConfig.optionPrices[_.findKey($widget.options.jsonConfig.index, options)];
            console.log("testing override");
            $productPrice.trigger(
                'updatePrice',
                {
                    'prices': $widget._getPrices(result, $productPrice.priceBox('option').prices)
                }
            );

        },
    });
});
```

any idea why it is not working?

Comment: kindly mention above file path so i can get some idea.

Comment: path is added - thanks for looking into this.

Comment: Have you deploy static content or not ?

Comment: Yes . just deployed: php bin/magento setup:di:compile

Comment: Which version you have tried?

Comment: it is for Magento 2.1 - I  see an issue.
in Magento 2.1, they use Magento_Swatches/js/swatch-renderer
instead of swatchRenderer which makes it a bit difficult to override.

Answer (score 0):

You have to follow bellow steps.

Delete var folder

Delete all files and folder inside pub/static/

Run bellow command for deploy content:

> `php bin/magento setup:static-content:deploy`

Delete browser cache.

Now you can check your changes is deploy or not.

Let me know if you have any difficulty.

Comment: I can see /pub/static/frontend/Magento/luma/en_US/X_Y/js/swatch-renderer.js
but, it is still not working.

Comment: Your theme is luma ?

Comment: Yes, it is Luma theme.

Comment: Now check file code which is run from core file or you module file. you can find out it in Network by inspect element.

Comment: I have this in my custom function
console.log("testing override"); 
since i see nothing in my console, it means that the code is never executed.

Comment: you can see file in network, open it from network. just check it path and code which is execute. and also remember if you are changing your file then you have to deploy static content.

Comment: loaded from  http://...../pub/static/frontend/Magento/luma/en_US/Magento_Swatches/js/swatch-renderer.js

Comment: it works if  in line 14 vendor\magento\module-swatches\view\frontend\templates\product\view\renderer.phtml 
i use this X_Y/js/swatch_renderer
but I have to copy the whole js content, not only edit the functions I need. 
anyone with a good solution?